# Using JFileChooser without opening the actual file

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser

I'm using the `JFileChooser` to allow a user to choose a `.txt` file that will later be processed by my program, however when the user chooses the file, it is actually opened by my computers default app (in my case TeXworks) as well as used by my program. Any idea how I can stop this?

```
File fileToOpen = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Comment: Cannot understand your question. You want to hide all files which are blocked by another programs? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFileChooser`'s `getSelectedFile()` method, returns a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object.
Use the `getAbsolutePath()` to get the absolute name to the file.

Modified example from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
System.out.println("You chose to open this directory: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

---

So in your case you just need to append `.getAbsolutePath()` to the end of your statement, like this:

```
File fileToOpen = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```